# Efficient drawing of primitives in openGL ES 2.0

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

I am writing a game on Android, and it is coming along well enough. I am trying to keep everything as efficient as possible, so I am storing as much as I can in Vertex Buffer Objects to avoid unnecessary CPU overhead. However the simple act of drawing lots of unrelated primitives, or even a varying length string of sprites efficiently (such as drawing text to the screen) is escaping me.

The purpose of these primitives is menus and buttons, as well as text.

For drawing the menus, I could just make a vertex array for each element (menu background, buttons, etc), but since they are all just quads, this feels very inefficient. I could also create a sort of drawQuad() function that lets me just transparently load a single saved vertex array with data for xy/height&width/color/texture/whatever. However, reloading each element of the array with the new coordinates and other data each time, to copy it to the Float Buffer (For C++ guys, this is a special step you have to do in Java to pass the data to GL) so I can resend it to the GPU also feels lacking in efficiency, though I don't know how else I could do it. (One boost in efficiency I could see is setting the quad coordinates to be a unit square and then using Uniforms to scale it, but this seems unscalable).

For text it is even worse since I don't know how long the text will be and don't want to have to create larger buffers for larger text (causing the GC to randomly fire later). The alternate is to draw each letter with a independent draw command, but this also seems very inefficient for even a hundred letters on the screen (Since I read that you should try to have as few draw commands as possible).

It is also possible that I am looking way too deep into the necessary optimization of openGL, but I don't want to back myself into a corner with some terrible design early on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try looking into the idea of interleaving data for your glDrawArrays calls.
Granted this link is for iphone, but there is a nice graphic at the bottom of the page that details this concept. http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/06/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-8.html

I'm going to assume for drawing your characters that you are specifying some vertex coords and some texture coords into some sort of font bitmap to pick the correct character.
So you could envision your FloatBuffer as looking like

[vertex 1][texcoord 1][vertex 2][texcoord 2][vertex 3][texcoord 3]

[vertex 2][texcoord 2][vertex 3][texcoord 3][vertex 4][texcoord 4]

The above would represent a single character in your sentence if you're using GL_TRIANGLES, and you could expand on this idea to have vertices 5 - 8 to represent the second character and so on and so forth. Now you could draw all of your text on screen with a single glDrawArrays call. Now you might be worried about having redundant data in your FloatBuffer, but the savings will be huge. For example, in rendering a teapot with 1200 vertices and having this redundant data in my buffer, I was able to get a very visible speed increase over calling glDrawArrays for each individual triangle maybe something like 10 times better.

I have a small demo on sourceforge where I use data interleaving to render the teapot I mentioned earlier.
Its the ShaderProgramTutorial.rar. https://sourceforge.net/projects/androidopengles/files/ShaderProgram/
Look in teapot.java in the onDrawFrame function to see it.

On a side note you might find some of the other things on that sourceforge page helpful in your future Android OpenGL ES 2.0 fun!